# ec2 gives bad request

Tags: aws

I'm deploying on ec2 instance, when I write the server_ip in the browser I get bad request

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

that's error from apache error_log

```
AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1, referer: http://server_ip/
```

and it give me so whenever I try to access any project
how to solve this problem

Comment: Where is the `/favicon.ico` file your trying to get does it exist?

Comment: what is this file, I'm trying to open php code file

Comment: that the icon file for your site look for it and add the path to the code that is calling it!

Comment: my code contains only echo "hello";

that's happenin also when I'm trying to open apache home page on ec2

Comment: Does this stop your site from loading?

Comment: yes, it does ..

Comment: Try adding an ico file for your site and see if the error goes away.

Comment: i get that error `Invalid URI in request GET / HTTP/1.1`